# Calculate limit of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\arcsin (x\ln 2)}}{{{2^{ - 3x}} - 1}}$

Tags: calculus

Calculate

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\arcsin (x\ln 2)}}{{{2^{ - 3x}} - 1}}$$

My try:

$$x\ln 2 \to 0
$$

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\arcsin (x\ln 2)}}{{{2^{ - 3x}} - 1}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{x\ln 2}}{{{2^{ - 3x}} - 1}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{x\ln 2}}{{ - 3x}} =  - \frac{{\ln 2}}{3}
$$

Right answer is: **$ - \frac{1}{3}$**

Where my error?

Comment: You're forgetting the exponent on the the numerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}(x\ln 2)}{2^{-3x}-1} = -\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{\sin^{-1}(x\ln 2)}{x\ln 2}\times x\ln 2 \times \frac{x}{8^x-1}\times \frac{1}{x}\times 8^x\right]$$

So we get $$\displaystyle  = -\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{\sin^{-1}(x\ln 2)}{x\ln 2}\right]\times \ln(2)\times \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{x}{8^x-1}\right]\times 1 = -\ln 2 \times \frac{1}{\ln (8)} = -\frac{\ln (2)}{3\ln (2)} = -\frac{1}{3}$$

above we have Used the formula

$\displaystyle \bullet\; \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}(y)}{y} = 1$ and $\displaystyle \bullet\; \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x} = \ln(a)$ and $\displaystyle \bullet\; \ln(m)^n = n\ln(m)$

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in transition step from  $2^{ - 3x} - 1$ to $-3x$.

Hint: use that $e^x = 1 + x +O(x^2)$.